# Why is this returning -1 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, datetime, date

```
d.getTime().toString().search(/Wed/i)
```

I don't get it... typeof returns string, and if i copy and paste "Wed Jul 14 2010 15:35:53 GMT-0700 (PST)" and save it to the var `str` and do `str.search(/Wed/i)` it returns `0` but when i do it like above i always get -1, even tho, as i said, it returns a string typeof.

Any ideas how to check if Wed is in that str?

Just for reference, i'm looping through 7 days, checking for Wed, if it's wed, i save the current date and break out of the loop. If you know a better way let me know. Right now im just doing a `while(x<=6)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date/getTime) on a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date) returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970, so won't contain the string `'Wed'`.

Perhaps you meant `d.toString().search(/Wed/i)` instead?

If `d` is an instance of `Date`, then a better way to check if it is a Wednesday would be to test if the result of [`getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) is 3:

```
d.getDay() == 3
```

Comment: Wow, im an idiot, thank you. I knew this... long day working with JS numbers apparently :)

Comment: Thanks, duh, changing it to 3. You rock

Answer (score 1):

The reason it returns -1 is that "Wed" will never appear in your string, because "getTime()" returns a big number: the number of milliseconds since the epoch.

Calling "toString()" on that big number still returns a big number, with the digits formatted as a string, as in "1278975122089".  It does NOT return the date and time, as in "Mon Jul 12 15:49:59 PDT 2010".

> The getTime() method returns the
>   number of milliseconds since midnight
>   of January 1, 1970 and the specified
>   date.

Try using the following instead, without the getTime() call:

```
d.toString().search(/Wed/i)
```